# "what does "make: *** [executable] Error 1" mean ?"

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, gnu

I made a makefile to compile a program. I do not know what went wrong with it.

```
    CPP = gcc
    CXXFLAGS = -I. -std=gnu++2a
    DEPS = Robot.h gene_pool.h generate_matrix.h generate_rand_coordinates.h constants.h
    OBJS = gene_pool.o generate_matrix.o generate_rand_coordinates.o main.o Robot.o

    %.o: %.cpp $(OBJS) $(DEPS)
            $(CPP) -c -o $@ $< $(CXXFLAGS)

    robot: $(OBJS) $(DEPS)
            $(CPP) -o $@ $^ $(CXXFLAGS)
```

Resulting error message :

```
      make: Circular gene_pool.o <- gene_pool.o dependency dropped.
    make: Circular generate_matrix.o <- gene_pool.o dependency dropped.
    make: Circular generate_matrix.o <- generate_matrix.o dependency dropped.
    make: Circular generate_rand_coordinates.o <- gene_pool.o dependency dropped.
    make: Circular generate_rand_coordinates.o <- generate_matrix.o dependency dropped.
    make: Circular generate_rand_coordinates.o <- generate_rand_coordinates.o dependency dropped.
    make: Circular main.o <- gene_pool.o dependency dropped.
    make: Circular main.o <- generate_matrix.o dependency dropped.
    make: Circular main.o <- generate_rand_coordinates.o dependency dropped.
    make: Circular main.o <- main.o dependency dropped.
    make: Circular Robot.o <- gene_pool.o dependency dropped.
    make: Circular Robot.o <- generate_matrix.o dependency dropped.
    make: Circular Robot.o <- generate_rand_coordinates.o dependency dropped.
    make: Circular Robot.o <- main.o dependency dropped.
    make: Circular Robot.o <- Robot.o dependency dropped.
    gcc -o robot gene_pool.o generate_matrix.o generate_rand_coordinates.o main.o Robot.o Robot.h gene_pool.h generate_matrix.h generate_rand_coordinates.h constants.h -I. -std=gnu++2a
    clang: error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files
    make: *** [robot] Error 1
```

I do not understand most of the message. Does it have anything to do with my code ?

Comment: You have circular dependencies. Your object-files shouldn't depend on each other.

Comment: Question. Why do you have header files on the `gcc` command line? They're almost never meant to be compiled directly. It's kinda looking like you might be unclear on what your `DEPS` is for.

Comment: @cHao: Yes. I am not clear about the DEPS for. I thought that they were supposed to be on the dependency list.

Answer (score 0):

To get you moving.

You can fix this by removing some stuff:

From this line remove OBJES

```
%.o: %.cpp $(OBJS) $(DEPS)
```

Should look like:

```
%.o: %.cpp         $(DEPS)
```

Otherwise every object file depends on all other object files. There will be cycles in this dependency which is what the error message is complaining about.

So an object file depends on its source file and the header that source file uses. Its unlikely it depends on all source files but it should not cause an issue (just it may force re-compilation more often then you would like).

From this line remove DEPS

```
robot: $(OBJS) $(DEPS)
```

Should look like this:

```
robot: $(OBJS)
```

The executable does not need to depend on the header files. If any of the object files is re-built then the executable will be re-built. So the extra DEPS does not add anything.

This is not a perfect Makefile but it should work for your use case.

Comment: Got an error after compile "
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "...clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) is there anything wrong with my code ? I compiled on IDE it was fine though

Comment: @w1583236 This means the make file is fine and is working. But this is a different. Error so ask a new question and be as specific as you can. Show the make error (copy and paste). It should also show the command it ran so run that manually and then run it again with the `-v` command to get more details. Post all of this information into the new question.